# XmlWriter to write Element String with Attribute

Tags: xml

I am using XmlWriter and I am wondering if some one ever tried to write the xml element string (leaf node) with attributes so that the output would look like

```
<book id='1' author='j.k.rowling' year='2010'>999</book>
```

instead of

```
<book id='1' author='j.k.rowling' year='2010'> 
    <book>999</book>
</book>
```

Comment: Um, shouldn't be any problems writing the first version, but hard to figure out what the problem is without seeing the code.

Comment: Well I am using one of the attributes as a label that contains spaces. And I dont want to change the xsl structure and just want to use something like <td> <xsl:attribute name="author"/> </td>. With the second version I think I will have to dig down one more level in xpath. I just want to be able to attach the attributes to the xml leaf node using XmlWriter function. That would be the goal.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: writer.WriteStartElement("book");
writer.WriteAttributeString("author", "j.k.rowling");
writer.WriteAttributeString("year", "1990");
writer.WriteElementString("books", bookPrice.ToString());
writer.WriteEndElement();

I wanna do all in one step because start and end element function creates a child element for element string. I could be wrong in manipulating but essentially what I want to achieve is just to attach attributes for elements using xmlwriter function.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use [WriteString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring.aspx)...

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("books.xml"))
{

    writer.WriteStartElement("book"); 
    writer.WriteAttributeString("author", "j.k.rowling"); 
    writer.WriteAttributeString("year", "1990");
    writer.WriteString("99");
    writer.WriteEndElement();                                

}
```

Comment: Never mind. I got it all wrong because in the xsl I didnt have idea how to get the value of attributes but I figured that out. Nothing wrong with xmlwriter. Actually it was my xsl template that was wrong.